# Parse string to datetime in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to parse a string to a date

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE("2021-02-03T07:19:49.661Z", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
```

But it refuses to work:

"Mismatch between format character '2' and string character '%'"

I know it's likely to do with the second argument, but I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the format string the first argument, then fix the milliseconds part:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ', "2021-02-03T07:19:49.661Z")
```

Comment: This returns "2021-02-03T07:19:49.661000" any way to truncate this to "2021-02-03T07:19:49" ?

Comment: SELECT DATETIME_TRUNC(PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ', "2021-02-03T07:19:49.661Z"), SECOND)

Comment: Great, I thought there was only TIMESTAMP_TRUNC , this is much cleaner than wrapping